# How To Know Which NSURLConnection Returned

Tags: ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to identify WHICH NSURLConnection did finish loading when there are multiple ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476302/how-to-identify-which-nsurlconnection-did-finish-loading-when-there-are-multiple)

I am getting weather information from a url. I use the same url and a different city for the parameter, for example (not my actual code in case I made an error):

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{        
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://weatherurl.com/xmlFeed.php?location=%@",[locations objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

How do I know which connection has returned in `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection`?

I am thinking about adding each connection into an array and then comparing the connection from the delegate method to the connections in my array, but I would like to know if there is a better/standard way. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplciate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476302/how-to-identify-which-nsurlconnection-did-finish-loading-when-there-are-multiple

Comment: I am not going to make countless `NSURLConnection`s, but I assume my use of an array is a correct solution then since it seems to be the same concept.

Comment: Subclassing `NSURLConnection` (to associate additional information like a tag or index) seems also elegant to me, see e.g. http://www.isignmeout.com/multiple-nsurlconnections-viewcontroller/.